# Problema al Inicializar array (TypeScript)

Tags: array, typescript

Estoy intentando copiar propiedades de un objeto (`response.projects[i].name`) a un array. Tengo esto :

```
response=>{
                if (response.projects){

                    this.projects=response.projects;

                    console.log(this.projects[0]);
                    for (var i=0;i<response.projects.length;i++){

                        if (typeof this.projects[i].name !="undefined"){
                            this.names[i]=this.projects[i].name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Sin embargo, obtengo el error

> cannot set property 0 of undefined

Refiriendose seguramente a `this.names[0]`. No se como tendría que escribir el código para que funcione.

Comment: Puedes mostrar que te da si haces consolé log sobre this.projetcs, porque puede que esté no tenga valor

Comment: Parece que `this.names` "no está disponible" dentro del bloque. Comprueba que lo has declarado como propiedad de la clase y es de tipo array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegúrate de que `this.names` está definido, poniendo antes del bucle algo como

```
this.names = this.names || [];
```